# Apache redirects to localhost

Tags: apache, wamp

I set up WAMP 3.1.9 on my laptop and want to access the website from LAN using my phone. Apache version is 2.4.39, I replaced the default virtualhost settings in the httpd-vhosts.conf file with the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I am using windows 10 and added httpd.exe to the firewall exceptions.

The problem is that, when I access my laptops LAN ip (192.168.2.8) from my phone, I get a "could not establish connection" error. When I look at the sites adress, it says 'localhost' instead of the LAN ip, so I'm suspecting that Apache redirects the request to localhost, but I cannot find the setting which does this nor am I able to find this online.

---

I **solved it** by reinstalling WAMP

1. I am now using using version 3.2.0.
2. Edited *httpd-vhosts.conf* and changed the line `Require local` to `Require all granted`.
3. Restarted all services
4. Cleared history of my phone
5. Attempted to reach the site from my phone, resulted in a connection time out but no redirect.
6. Added httpd.exe as an exception to windows firewall. This is done by: start > type: Windows Defender Firewall > Allow app or feature ... > change settings > allow another app.. > browse > C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.41\bin\httpd.exe > add > ok
7. cleared history of phone again.
8. Successfully reached the site on my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

See [the documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servername):

> The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port
>   that the server uses to identify itself.
>
> ServerName is used (possibly in conjunction with ServerAlias) to
>   uniquely identify a virtual host, when using name-based virtual hosts.
>
> Additionally, this is used when creating self-referential redirection
>   URLs when UseCanonicalName is set to a non-default value.

Since you said the `ServerName` was `localhost`, Apache redirects to `localhost` when it generates a redirect.

If you want the canonical name to be `192.168.2.8` then use that.

Comment: I thought about that, but in all the online discussions about this topic `ServerName localhost` and `ServerAlias localhost` are used. Which is why I did not think of it as the cause of the problem. Anyway, I have done a reinstall of WAMP and it is currently working with localhost as servername.Based on your comment I have changed serverAlias to the laptops IP to prevent possible future issues.

I am still wondering why my post is being downvoted though